# Eval() for setting Form controls property

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, eval

I work on an Access VBA 2013 application, and this part of the project focuses on form controls and buttons.

I want to lock/unlock control modification thanks to buttons set aside.
For more genericity, I wanted the subs called by the events call homemade functions:

```
Sub LockAssociateControl(fctName As String, val As Boolean)
    Dim code As String
    code = "Forms!" & getModuleName & ".Controls!" & fctName & ".Locked = " & CStr(val)
    Debug.Print (code) 'just to test
    Eval code
End Sub
```

*(getModuleName is also a homemade function that returns the right name of the module calling the function)*

For example, this one is called like below:

```
Private Sub FirstName_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
    Call LockAssociateControl("FirstName", True)
End Sub
```

and in "code" variable, it sets "Forms!Module1.Controls!Name.Locked = True" *(with Module1 generated by getModuleName, and Name as the parameter (I haven't found better yet))*.

Now I want this code evaluated in order to avoid me from hard coding every event sub.

My problem is that an error occurs at the `Eval()` line and says:

> Error Code: 2770. The object to which you reffered in the Visual Basic procedure as an OLE object is not an OLE object

I've looked around StockOverflow and others forums to find out what's wrong with `Eval()`, and I found that this function's behavior is not made for what I want. So I tried to find another way to do that, as `Evaluate` function doesn't exist in Access, etc, but I found nothing really helpful.

I tried to use `DoCmd` or `Call` or various transformations on the parameter string of `Eval()`, but nothing has worked so far...

So here's my question: Do any of you have a solution for that problem? And if not, do you know an alternative not to have to write in every event function full statements like: `Forms!Module1.Controls!Name.Locked = False`?

Comment: How about first testing if your approach works at all by hardcoding it? If that works, then try eval().

Comment: Due to my incapacity to find generic way to do, I indeed did a copied verion of the form I'm working on, and I'm currently dealing with this version to work other aspects of the code. That's a temporary solution but I hope not get stuck with this version forever, due to its non-flexibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you want easier without using `Eval()` ...

```vb
Sub LockAssociateControl(fctName As String, pVal As Boolean)
    Forms(getModuleName).Controls(fctName).Locked = pVal
End Sub
```

Note I changed the argument name from `val` to `pVal` to avoid confusing it with the `Val()` function.